# Bootstrap collapsed navbar showing empty

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the hamburger menu in my nicely collapsed bootstrap navbar on my phone, the layout slides to the side as expected, but shows me an empty white (or whatever body background colour I have) bar instead of the navigation. Closer inspection with firebug showed that upon clicking the button, some classes got changed on the `navbar-collapse`but it remains tagged as invisible.

I have recompiled Bootstrap from LESS to change the point at which it collapses, but the issue seems persistent even with 'vanilla' bootstrap.

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header" style="padding-right: 0px; min-width: 50px;">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs hidden-sm" href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="padding-right: 0px;"></span></a><a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md" href="index.html">De Fijnkost</a>
    </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-example-2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="vleeswaren.html" class="btn btn-white btn-simple">Fijne Vleeswaren</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="gerechten.html" class="btn btn-white btn-simple">Bereide Gerechten</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="salades.html" class="btn btn-white btn-simple">Eigen salades</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="kaas.html" class="btn btn-white btn-simple">Kazen &amp; Kaasschotels</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="broodjes.html" class="btn btn-white btn-simple">Belegde Broodjes</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="index.html#contact" class="btn btn-white btn-fill">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="nieuws.php" class="btn btn-white btn-fill">Nieuws</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-white btn-fill" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Bestel&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="kaasschotels.html">Kaasschotel</a>
              </li>
              <li class="disabled">
                <a href="broodjes.html#bestel">Broodjes</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid-->
</nav>
```

Same thing happens on pages without the `transparent` or `navbar-fixed-top` class. `transparent` is added by my CSS. Page is visible on [defijnkost.be](http://defijnkost.be)

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Comment: yeah, give me a minute. I have maybe slightly too much css files and I don't have SSL on my site so JSFiddle won't accept my external resources...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .navbar-collapse is set to `display: none !important` as far as I can see.

If you set it to `display: block` in your mobile view media query it should show up just fine.

Comment: Yep, you are right. There was apperently a line in a css source I used from someone that was not entirely right. EDIT: It was trying to override the collapse point where I had done that in custom compiled Bootstrap.